# While loop not breaking when trying to convert from while not loop to while loop

Tags: python

I'm working on a little game function asking for the player to input a marker 'X' or 'O' to represent them. When I tried to use while loop instead of while not loop, it turned out to keep asking for an input no matter what you put in. I have been researching a while and found nothing, this might be a really simple mistake so a short reply can help me a lot. Thanks everyone!

```
def player_input():
    marker=''

    while (marker != 'X' or marker != 'O'):
        marker = input('Choose your marker ').upper()

    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X','O')
    else:
        return ('O','X')

def player_input():
    marker = ''

    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = input('Player 1: Do you want to be X or O? ').upper()

    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X', 'O')
    else:
        return ('O', 'X')
```

Comment: Your two expressions are not equivalent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

Boolean Logic: `!(A v B) = (!A ^ !B)`

> v - or
>
> ^ - and
>
> ! - not

Your condition in the upper function should be :

```
while (marker != 'O' and player1 != 'X'):
```

i.e., `and`, instead of `or`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let's split into pieces

(marker != 'X' or player1 != 'O')

If we input 'X' then :
marker != 'X'  -> 'X' != 'X' -> False
player1 != 'O' -> 'X' != 'O' -> True
(marker != 'X' or player1 != 'O') -> (False or True)

The output will be True 


not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O')

marker == 'X' -> 'X' == 'X' -> True
marker == 'O' -> 'X' == 'O' -> False
(marker == 'X' or marker == 'O') -> (True or False)
True 

and not will make it to be False 

If you want to make it work it should be :

not (marker == 'X') or not (marker == 'O')
```